# Meteor/Cordova: accounts-password breaks app on login/signup

Tags: cordova, meteor, biginteger, bcrypt, meteor-accounts

I'm diving back into a Meteor project that is a couple years old, and now I'm trying to deploy it to the App Store with Cordova.

I've upgraded to Meteor 1.7.0.4 and the app builds and runs just fine on web. Now I'm following the Meteor guide for their Cordova integration (https://guide.meteor.com/mobile.html).

The app builds just fine when I run "meteor build ios" and I'm able to view the app's sign in page via the iOS Simulator. But as soon as I try to login or create a new account, nothing happens after I hit submit, and I get a bunch of errors in the Safari debugger.

[image]

The first error comes from a Meteor dependency called BigInteger. I think it may be something related to ES6 because it doesn't recognize this spread operator syntax:

[image]

Then the next error is related to accounts-password, so it may have something to do with getting the mobile device to connect to the server. I don't know much about this, but I've read that sometimes there are issues around this area.

I've ran "meteor reset" and removed and then reinstalled all the dependencies, but still no luck.

Anyone come across this before?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Check out [this github thread](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/10143) it's pretty recent and looks like it has to do with updating the SRP package to use ES6. Give `meteor update srp` a shot.